# How can I add a timeout to this web crawler?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, web-crawler, threadpoolexecutor

I wanted to make a web crawler using requests and ThreadPoolExecutor. My problem is that even though in the while loop I've made a sort of timeout, the program doesn't stop.

```
def StartCrawler(base_link, timeout):
Session = requests.Session()
LINKS_LIST.put(base_link)
HASH_CODES.add(CreateHash(base_link))
start_time = time.time()
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=35) as executor:
    while time.time() - start_time <= timeout: 
        try:
            target_url = LINKS_LIST.get()
            executor.submit(GetSessionLinks, Session, target_url)
        except:
            print("error")
            continue
```

How should I approach this problem and how could I stop the program after a given amount of time?

Code Section:

```
def GetSessionLinks(session, base_url: str):
    page = session.get(base_url).text
    for link in re.finditer(REGEX_PATTERN, page):
        url = link.group()
        hash_code = CreateHash(url)
        if hash_code not in HASH_CODES:
            suffix = GetSuffix(url)
            if suffix not in EXCEPTIONS:
                LINKS_LIST.put(url)
            HASH_CODES.add(hash_code)
            outFILE.write(url)
            outFILE.write('\n')

def StartCrawler(base_link, timeout):
    Session = requests.Session()
    LINKS_LIST.put(base_link)
    HASH_CODES.add(CreateHash(base_link))
    start_time = time.time()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=35) as executor:
        while time.time() - start_time <= timeout: 
            try:
                target_url = LINKS_LIST.get()
                executor.submit(GetSessionLinks, Session, target_url)
            except:
                print("error")
                continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    StartCrawler('https://carrefour.ro/', 3)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: You may have to reconsider how you're doing this as I'm fairly sure that requests Session is **not** thread safe

Comment: you may need `session.get(..., timeout=...)` `session.post(..., timeout=...)`